# Remove a word at the end of string if matches certain word in java

Tags: java, string

Need a solution for the below scenario,

Input String --> **Abs_es_ten_V1**

Expected output --> **Abs_es_ten**

For various input string at the end it may be like --> _v23 ,_v6, _v78 or different

So how can I remove the words at the end of string starting with "_v"

Comment: You can either `split` the String at every `_` and then re-join it, you can also use `indexOf` and `substring` or use the cleaner approach using a regular expression. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: split by underscore, check if last element of array matches V[0-9]+ and depending on that conditionally rejoin your string.

Comment: iterate from the end checking if _v or _V was found, and also if all the characters so far were digits. If _v or _V was found, then use substring on your string to remove unwanted sufix. Or, use regex

Answer (score 2):

Use a regex replacement:

```java
String input1 = "Abs_es_ten_V1";
String input2 = "Abs_es_ten_X2";
input1 = input1.replaceAll("_V[^_]*$", "");
input2 = input2.replaceAll("_V[^_]*$", "");
System.out.println(input1);  // Abs_es_ten
System.out.println(input2);  // Abs_es_ten_X2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, a bit more complicated:

We use `substring()` with

- start index (**inclusive**): `lastIndexOf("_")` to take the index of the last underscore
- end index (**exclusive**): `lastIndexOf("_") + 2` to keep the char after the last underscore in our substring

and check if it `equals` with "_V".

If it is true, then we substring the inputs without the characters after the final underscore.

```java
String input1 = "Abs_es_ten_V1";
String input2 = "Abs_es_ten_X2";

if ( input1.substring(input1.lastIndexOf("_"), (input1.lastIndexOf("_")+2)).equals("_V") )
    input1 = input1.substring(0, input1.lastIndexOf("_"));

if ( input2.substring(input2.lastIndexOf("_"), (input2.lastIndexOf("_")+2)).equals("_V") )
    input2 = input2.substring(0, input2.lastIndexOf("_"));
```

Comment: @KesavanBalakrishnan You are welcome. Please accept my answer or Tim's answer as the correct one now that they solve your problem. To do this, click on the grey mark next to the voting section of our answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved with another approach.hope it's help.

```
String input = "Abs_es_Ven_V1";
String uInput = input.replaceAll("_", " ");
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(uInput.split(" "));
int size = words.size() - 1;
List<String> op = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) 
    {
       if (words.get(i) != words.get(size)) {
                    op.add(words.get(i));
       }
       if (words.get(i).equals(words.get(size)) && !words.get(i).contains("V")) {
                    op.add(words.get(i));
       }
    }
String result = String.join("_",op);
System.out.println("result ::"+result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use split() to get a string before a specific character like below

```
String s= "Abs_es_ten_V1";
String[] parts = s.split("_V");
String result = parts[0];
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: What if it has an input like `Abs_es_Ven_V1`? I don't know if there is any chance of this input.

Comment: for `Abs_es_Ven_V1` input it will also give you a output `Abs_es`.

Comment: But this is wrong. For input `Abs_es_Ven_V1`, the output should be `Abs_es_Ven`. Because only the *last* '_V' indicates the version (and must be removed). 
My only concern is if there are inputs like this one. If not, then your answer is OK.

Comment: because string are divided into `3 parts : Abs_es, en and 1' and all there parts are stored in array. So when accessing the value at index 0  it will be` Abs_es`.